# Why won't my log in page receive any information?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, md5

I made a login page for my website.  The connection to the database is fine, and I am typing in to the login form the correct values that are in the database.  I have a md5 on the password in both the database and the code.  Yet, when I check to see if any rows come back, there are none.  I would just like another set of eyes to look over what is probably a stupid mistake.

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$password = md5($password);  

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = '$password' AND email='$email' AND activated='1'";
$queryrun = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryrun)) {
$fname = $row['firstname'];
echo $fname;
}

$logincheck = mysql_num_rows($queryrun);

if ($logincheck > 0) {
echo 'good, you are in our database';
} else {
echo 'sorry, you are not in our database';
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>

</head>
<body>

Login <br />

<form action="login.php" method="POST">
Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the return value from the query? Is the code run? What do you get if you remove the WHERE clause from your query? What if you move the `mysql_num_rows` call to before the `mysql_fetch_assoc` loop?

Comment: Your open to blind sql injection, Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @andrewsi ok I removed the WHERE clause and there must be a problem there because I have 2 rows in the database but none are showing up.  Connection to database problem?

Comment: You've got some cargo-cult programming going on. Presumably emails are unique in the database, so using a `while()` to retrieve what should only ever be a SINGLE record is pointless.

Comment: Do the user's "activated" rows == 1?

Comment: Also, just for notice. You shouldn't use md5 for hashing your passwords, as it is deemed unsafe now. You should use something more powerful. I might recommend PHPass.

Comment: @elliotanderson - try looking in `mysql_error()` - it'll tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: i figured out the answer